# bash: enter every folder, search for filetype. If missing. download that file

Tags: bash, recursive

new bash-beginner here. As a start into scripting I want to write a simple bash-script, which enters every folder within a specific path, check for filetype and if it is missing, do a certain wget-command.

folder-excample:

**home-path**

```
-folder1 
--file1.mp3 
-folder2 
--file2.mp3 
--file2.sfv 
-folder3 
--file3.mp3 
--file3.sfv
```

**What do I want to automate?**

home-path is known. Enter every folder in it (folder1, -2 & -3), check if there is a .sfv in it. If NOT, then execute a wget-command. The wget-command I managed to code myself. But I would love to get some help for the rest of the script.

Any idea, how I can get this to work? Many thanks for any hints!

Kind regards,

Thomas

Comment: In your `home-path` you say there are directories. Are there directories within directories that you want to test too?

Comment: You say that for each directory we need to "_check if there is a `.sfv` in it_". Any file ending with `.sfv`, or is there a pattern that can be derived from the directory name?

Comment: How does the `wget` command vary by file or directory?

Comment: Please [edit your question](https://unix.stackexchange.com/posts/736823/edit) to provide these details. Don't reply here in the comments

Comment: Your example seems you search mp3 files which have no corresponding sfv file. Of this is the case, a script could be easier to write.

Comment: Given the example directory structure, explain (in the question) what the script needs to do and why.